# How to Hide Zoom links in Address bar of any Browser

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a project were client wants to hide Shared link to their student because client thinking that student sharing their links of zoom meeting with another students of another organization.(so the client doesn't wants to share links due to client is teaching a Paid Course).

So I'm Thinking that what if we open link window as popup window.
but the problem is `target=_blank` and opening new window not popup windows.
how to solve this thing?

I'm using following code of php

```
echo "<td><a href=" . $row['r_link'] ." target=_blank>". $row['r_topic'] ."</td>";
```

Comment: Security by obscurity is not security. And a popup tab or window won't hide anything anyway. If the link is there in the HTML, anyone can grab it if they want to. The solution is to check that everyone who joins the meeting is registered and paid for the course, and kick out those who haven't. Make sure the meeting has an access code. You can't stop people sharing things ultimately, so your client has to have a separate process to verify those who are joining their meetings. It's not really a technology problem, to be honest.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - otherwise, please explain how this question is related to SQL, or PHP Usually, PHP itself cannot modify anything shown in the browser, it can only print the markup that handles this

Answer (score 0):

I had Solved this Problem using iframe. iframe hides the address from the normal user (not saying from a hacker).
I added all link details in html form with input type "hidden" and posted/set target on the next page. Where php fetches parameters of link and put in iframe src tag. Code as Fallows.

in HTML

```
<input type=hidden name=r_id value=$id>
```

in next page PHP and HTML

```
$r_link = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['r_id']);

<iframe src="<?php echo $r_link ?>"></iframe>
```

Thank You,
in this way I have solved my issue of hiding the meeting link.

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (which should escape a string that should get inserted in a database) for escaping markup? `htmlspecialchars`or anything similar might be better suited

Comment: Okay so , i have stored my zoom meeting links and passcode in database then I used a table where all links are showing dynamically using php while loop .using while loop I fetched details like id,link_url,and passcode from database and added input type hidden where a putted id of link as posted as form in next page . after submit button it goes to next page where mysqli cmd fateches id from form posted data after that it again fetch data form database using sql cmd where id equal to above and fetches link of zoom meeting and put in a iframe src.if you want code contact me on linked in.

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it